# Javascript not incrementing a variable

Tags: javascript

I would like to keep count every time the user clicks a the `add row` button. Here's the code I have that's not working.

```js
function add_more_row() {
  var rows_count = ParseInt(document.getElementById("rows_count").value);
  rows_count += 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="rows_count" />
<input onclick="add_more_row();" type="button" value="add row" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just so you know, the statement that you've read previous/related questions isn't helpful if you don't link to what questions you're referring to and describe why they didn't help.

Comment: What is being displayed in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code only gets the value and increases it, does not assign the value to the input field. Add this line after the increment statement:

```
document.getElementById("rows_count").value = rows_count;
```

Also it's `parseInt()` with lowercase `p` not `ParseInt()`.

```js
function add_more_row() {
  var inputRow = document.getElementById("rows_count"),
      rows_count = parseInt(inputRow.value);
  rows_count += 1;
  inputRow.value = rows_count;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="rows_count" />
<input onclick="add_more_row();" type="button" value="add row" />
```

Comment: Retrieving the element from the DOM twice is sloppy.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function add_more_row() {
  var rows_count = parseInt(document.getElementById("rows_count").value);
  rows_count += 1;
  document.getElementById("rows_count").value= rows_count;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="rows_count" />
<input onclick="add_more_row();" type="button" value="add row" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you declare the variable inside the function.
So, the variable does not increase.

```
 var rows_count=ParseInt(document.getElementById("rows_count").value);
 function add_more_row()
 {
   rows_count += 1;
 }
```

Comment: Nope, I only need that variable inside the function scope. Thank you though.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work. And you haven't fixed the typo with `ParseInt`.